# Data not updating to the database c# datagridview

Tags: c#, ms-access, datagridview

i wanted to update the database using datagridview, i already can edit it, but it didn't update to the database.

How do i fix that?

Here is my code:

There are buttons in my forms, one of it is "Edit" button, which is refer to "EditingDatabase" function, the other one is "OK" button, which is updating the data to the database (the code can be found in this below code, i mention it at the code).

```
private void EditingDatabase(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable _dt = (DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource;

            if (_dt.DefaultView.Count > 0)
            {
                int rowNum = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;
                int productCode = Convert.ToInt32(_dt.DefaultView[rowNum]["ProductCode"]);
                int quantity = Convert.ToInt32(_dt.DefaultView[rowNum]["Quantity"]);
                int price = Convert.ToInt32(_dt.DefaultView[rowNum]["Price"]);

                using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    string commandSelect = "SELECT [Quantity], [Price] FROM [Table] WHERE [ProductCode] = @ProductCode";
                    string commandUpdate = "UPDATE [Table] SET [Quantity] = @Quantity, [Price] = @Price WHERE [ProductCode] = @ProductCode";

                    conn.Open();

                    using (OleDbCommand _cmdSelect = new OleDbCommand(commandSelect, conn))
                    using (OleDbCommand _cmdUpdate = new OleDbCommand(commandUpdate, conn))
                    {
                        _cmdSelect.Parameters.Add("@ProductCode", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Integer);
                        _cmdSelect.Parameters["@ProductCode"].Value = productCode;

                        _cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add("ProductCode", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Integer);

                        _cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add("@Quantity", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Integer);

                        _cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add("@Price", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Integer);

                        using (OleDbDataReader dReader = _cmdSelect.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (dReader.Read())
                            {
                                _cmdUpdate.Parameters["@ProductCode"].Value = productCode;
                                _cmdUpdate.Parameters["@Quantity"].Value = quantity;
                                _cmdUpdate.Parameters["@Price"].Value = price;

                                int numberOfRows = _cmdUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }

                            dReader.Close();
                        }
                    }

                    conn.Close();
                }

                if (_choice.comboBox1.Text == "English") // THIS IS WHERE THE "OK" BUTTON FUNCTION RUNS
                {
                    System.Media.SoundPlayer _sounds = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\Windows\Media\Windows Exclamation.wav");
                    _sounds.Play();
                    MessageBox.Show("Updated Successfully!", "Updated");

                    ShowButtons(sender, e);

                    DisableColumnEdited(sender, e);
                }
            }

            else
            {
                if (_choice.comboBox1.Text == "English")
                {
                    System.Media.SoundPlayer _sounds = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\Windows\Media\Windows Exclamation.wav");
                    _sounds.Play();
                    MessageBox.Show("There is no Data in the Selected Row!", "Error");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
```

**Edited**

This below is the screenshot of my datagridview in the program, the datagridview are connected to the database table named `Table`:

[image]

Thank you.

I appreciate your answer!

Comment: Sorry to ask you silly question but have you try it by closing ms-access data base and update and then open it.

Comment: It is okay, feel free to ask :D. Yes, i already tried that. But the data hasn't change either.
I open the ms-access database only for the checking, other than that closed all the times.

Comment: What value you get in numberofRows ?

Comment: The value that i got is 0 sir Jaggen, for numberOfRows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong syntax in the `UPDATE` statement. It should be

```
   string query = "UPDATE [Table] SET [Quantity] = @Quantity, [Price] = @Price " + 
                  "WHERE [ProductCode] = @ProductCode";
```

Also, you are using OleDb, and OleDb requires that you add the parameters in the same order in which they appear in the command statement, so you need to write

```
_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", quantity);
_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", price);
_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductCode", productCode);
```

**[OleDb doesn't support named parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2)**, in the UPDATE statement you could use a simple question mark as parameter placeholder and name your parameters in the AddWithValue with whatever name you like.  However the syntax used (the @Quantity) is also supported.
The important point is: Add the parameters in the order in which they appears.

Finally, to update the database the only command required is

```
  int numberOfRows = _cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The code around the ExecuteNonQuery seems wrong if you expect that that code updates the grid. You are recreating the _adapter variable without any SELECT command....

Comment: Okay. I never know that parameters must be in same order with `UPDATE` Statement. Thanks. But, it is not working Steve. The database didn't update. Should i change `"AddWithvalue"` with "Add" and add this `"System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Integer"`?

Comment: Do you get any error message? Did you change the UPDATE statement above? How do you check if the database has been modified?

Comment: No, i didn't get any error message, and i already change the `UPDATE` Statement as you wrote it at above. 

I knew it because i checked it in the `Access` file where the database located after i modified the data.

So, in order to update data to the database (to working), i need to provide to ways of commands? one of it is `SELECT` and the last one is `UPDATE` itself, isn't it?

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on the final line (_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery) and execute it, you should see the value of numberOfRows. If it is different from zero then your update has been applied (and probably you are looking to a different database file). If it is zero and no error then your condition (WHERE ProductCode = ...) fails to identify any record to update.  To use an OleDbDataAdapter for INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE operation you could [look at this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10174549/using-oledbdataadapter-to-update-a-datatable-c-sharp)

Comment: Okay, i will look at it, and also the numberOfRows is 0 and i got different error, which is `no value given for one or more required paramaters`. I am sorry, i edited the above question code.

Comment: Missing the ProductCode parameter for the cmdUpdate

Comment: aaah yes, it is --"
Thanks Sir Steve! But, i still dunno how to solve the problem, why the database didn't updating --"

Comment: So are you sure that there is a `ProductCode` like the one you search for in your `Table`? By the way, do you really have a datatable named `Table`?

Comment: Yeah, i have table named `Table`. I use `dataGridView` to display it  from the database, the table in the database named `Table`. I already posted the screenshot of datagridview on the program in the question above (sorry for the late post and not give the screenshot earlier)

Comment: Again, your code doesn't add the parameters in the correct order; in that way, at the parameter for the ProductCode will be assigned the value set for the Price, of course no record to update will be found

Comment: aaah yes, it is working already sir Steve! Just because i put the cmdUpdate for the ProductCode, before the executeReader --"
Thanks again sir!