# Delete Row from datagridview using button en each row

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, datagridview

I have a  show delete button of each row  for delete from database permanently, how can delete data from DB ?

The following code shows delete button of each row. I have user Oracle Database 
**Where I have write query for delete ?**

```
DataGridViewLinkColumn Deletelink = new DataGridViewLinkColumn();
Deletelink.UseColumnTextForLinkValue = true;
Deletelink.HeaderText = "delete";
Deletelink.DataPropertyName = "lnkColumn";
Deletelink.LinkBehavior = LinkBehavior.SystemDefault;
Deletelink.Text = "Delete";
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(Deletelink);
```

I have write the code for delete but I have fail

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.ColumnIndex == 5)
  {
    empid = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["empid"].Value);
    OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter("delete  from apps where appsid= '"+empid+"'", con);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    adp.Fill(dt);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    dataGridView1.Refresh();
```

Comment: We don't know enough about your setup.  If you are going to delete a row in the database, you are going to need an ID or Key.

Comment: i have edit the question  i  am try to  solution  using  grid index

Comment: _dataGridView2_ or _dataGridView1_ ? Why you are setting the datatable as datasource of the dataGridView2?

Comment: it's my mistake code should be dataGridView1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A delete command issued as constructor for a OleDbDataAdapter is not correct. However the adapter will execute the command nevertheless. But surely you cannot expect a delete command to be used to fill a datatable.
You still need a SELECT.

Usually this is done removing the row from the grid (this marks the underlying row as *deleted* then, when you want to save the changes to the database, you should use the orginal DataAdapter and the original DataTable used to initially fill the grid to issue the [Update method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.update.aspx)

This is well explained here [Using OleDbDataAdapter to Update a DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10174549/using-oledbdataadapter-to-update-a-datatable-c-sharp)

Or you could do the update yourself using a separate command and reloading the datatable

```
// Delete the record on the db
empid = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["empid"].Value);
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("delete from apps where appsid= @id", con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = empid;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

// reload the grid with the updated info from the db
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from apps", con);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
dataGridView1.Refresh();
```

This of course has the drawback to hit two times the database and reloading everything each time you delete a row.

Comment: i have use  empid as string variable which is row delete using @id?

Comment: That's the parameter 'name' whose value is the empid's value